# Как получить RGB пикселя из bitmap

Tags: java, android-studio

```
final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
```

получил битмап изображения, пытаюсь получить RGB пикселя по координатам х:10 у:10 и  записать его на координаты х:11 у:11
попробовал так `selectedImage.getPixel(10,11)`
но оно возвращает такое значение -8155736. Как мне получить цвет в формате `#ffffff` для стеганографии?

Comment: А чем вас `-8155736` собственно не устраивает, какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: мне надо получить цвет в пормате #fffff для стеганографии

Comment: Посмотрите, `selectedImage.getPixel` вам отдает значение в виде знакового или беззнакового числа? Вероятно, вам нужно получить беззнаковое и преобразовать его в HEX.

Comment: Как на счет `Integer.toHexString(i);` или `String.format("#%x", i)` (второй вариант добавит `#` в начале, к первому придется прикрутить через `+`)

Answer (score 0):

Вы уже получайте `RGB`*, чтобы превратить в цвет сделайте следующее: `Color c = new Color(rgb)`, а что бы получать цвета сделайте так: `c.getRed()` `c.getGreen()` `c.getBlue()`, для RGB `c.getRGB()`. Для конвертации в HEX используйте`Integer.toHexString(число);`

---

*Для примера сделайте так: `System.out.println(Color.RED.getRGB());`